# Is it possible to establish a reference against multiple columns within a row in the same table?

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I am trying to design a table that can hold player data chosen by users for their team in a fantasy cricket game. Below are the column names.

```
-------------
Id_Member
Id_Match
Bat_P1
Bat_P2
Bat_P3
Bat_P4
Wkt_P5
All_P6
Bwl_P7
Bwl_P8
Bwl_P9
Bwl_P10
Bwl_P11
```

Now, the user can select one out of these 11 players as the captain.  I thought of adding one more column called 'cap_PP' which can hold that value but this must be one from the chosen 11 (and cannot be anything else).

This question might be totally meaningless but I just wanted to be sure before looking for other options.

I tried to use google and all i got was 'recursive one-to-one' reference which is not the same as what I am trying to do.  And then I found that there is SQL CHECK constraint but again not for my problem.

The last resort is to code this constraint in the front-end but I would really prefer to keep it on the DB end (if possible).

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. A reference is defined by the query, not by the data in the table. In other words: a reference in the data is just a number or string, not more. It is how it is interpreted what makes it interesting. And you certainly can join data within the same table.

Comment: How about adding just a number fr om 1 - 11 that choses the column as "the column that holds the team captain " ?

Comment: @Fildor: Simple and Elegant.  This should work for my case.  Thank you.

Comment: @arkascha: Sorry that I used the term 'reference' more liberally out of its actual context.  I did not know the term for what I was looking.  Fildor's solution would work for me though.  Thanks for pitching in.

Comment: See normalization. (why has no one suggested this already? - I despair for mankind)